# Counting occurrences within list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am loading numbers from a text file into a list, and in that regard, everything works fine!  But now I need to know how many times each number occured in the list.  Below is my whole program that I have pieced together by searching this site.

```
row = []  
textfile = open('take5_3.txt', 'r')
yourResult = [line.split('-') for line in textfile]
row.append(yourResult)    
print (yourResult)
```

Any time I put some sort of line that is suppose to count my result, I get one because it is only counting the list and not the items within the list.

Comment: what? Its not clear what you are asking for

Comment: [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) are all useful for counting things.

Comment: And for a small alphabet over a long string/list, repeated calls to the builtin `count` method are surprisingly fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joran has commentted, your question is really not clear. I will try to fill in the blank here.

```
textfile = open('take5_3.txt', 'r')
yourResult = [line.split('-') for line in textfile.readlines()] # use readline to read from the file
# You probably need to flatten the content in yourResult.
# Assume now yourResult is something like this ['a', 'a', 'bdbd', 'bbc', 'bbc']
# you can use Counter to do the counting
from collections import Counter
print Counter(yourResult)
```

And here is the output

```
Counter({'a': 2, 'bbc': 2, 'bdbd': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a dictionary with the number as the key and the count of the number as the value.  just keep incrementing the value as you go along.